# How to optimize the search algorithm for large 2d-array?

Tags: python, arrays, synchronization

After adding a line of code

```py
pathResult.append(find_max_path(arr, a + 1, b + 1, path))
```

began to run slowly, but without this code it does not work correctly. How can i optimize the code? The function looks for the path with the maximum number of points in a two-dimensional array where values equal to 100 lie predominantly on the main diagonal. Rows can have the same value equal to 100, but in any column the value 100 is one or none. Full code:

```py
arr = [
    [000,000,000,000,000,100,000],
    [000,000,000,000,000,000,000],
    [000,000,100,000,000,000,000],
    [000,100,000,000,000,000,000],
    [100,000,000,000,000,100,000],
    [000,000,000,000,100,000,000],
    [000,000,000,000,000,000,000],
    [000,000,000,000,000,000,000]]

def find_max_path(arr, a=0, b=0, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []
    while (a < len(arr)) and (b < len(arr[a])):
        if arr[a][b] == 100:
            path.append({"a": a, "b": b})
            b += 1
        else:
            try:
                if arr[a + 1][b + 1] == 100:
                    a += 1
                    b += 1
                    continue
            except IndexError:
                pass
            check = []
            for j in range(b + 1, len(arr[a])):
                if arr[a][j] == 100:
                    check.append({"a": a, "b": j})
                    break
            if not check:
                a += 1
                continue
            i = a + 1
            while i < len(arr):
                if arr[i][b] == 100:
                    check.append({"a": i, "b": b})
                    break
                i += 1
            pathResult = []
            for c in check:
                pathNew = path[:]
                pathNew.append({"a": c["a"], "b": c["b"]})
                pathResult.append(find_max_path(arr, c["a"] + 1, c["b"] + 1, pathNew))
            pathResult.append(find_max_path(arr, a + 1, b + 1, path))
            maximum = 0
            maxpath = []
            for p in pathResult:
                if len(p) > maximum:
                    maximum = len(p)
                    maxpath = p[:]
            if maxpath:
                return maxpath
        a += 1
    return path

print(find_max_path(arr))
```

UPDATE1: add two `break` in inner loops (execution time is halved)

Output:

```
[{'a': 4, 'b': 0}, {'a': 5, 'b': 4}]
```

UPDATE2

Usage.
I use this algorithm to synchronize two streams of information. I have words from the text along the lines, about which it is known where they are in the text of the book `L_word`. By columns, I have recognized words from the audiobook, about which the recognized word itself is known and when it was spoken in the audio stream `R_word`.
It turns out two arrays of words. To synchronize these two lists, I use something like this

```py
from rapidfuzz import process, fuzz
import numpy as np

window = 50
# L_word = ... # words from text book
# R_word = ... # recognize words from audiobook
L = 0
R = 0
L_chunk = L_word[L:L+window]
R_chunk = R_word[R:R+window]
scores = process.cdist(L_chunk, 
                       R_chunk, 
                       scorer=fuzz.ratio, 
                       type=np.uint8, 
                       score_cutoff=100)
p = find_max_path(scores)
# ... path processing ...
```

...
as a result of all the work, we get something like this video book with pagination and subtitles synchronized with audio [download 3GB](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/TyspVE6Yk4eDuw)

UPDATE3: adding this code reduces the execution time by almost ten times!

```py
try:
    if arr[a + 1][b + 1] == 100:
        a += 1
        b += 1
        continue
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Comment: What resource are you needing to optimize for? I am guessing that ram or memory is being depleted, then needing to write data causing a bottle neck

Comment: everything is fine with memory, but it slows down in time already with an array size of 50x50. It is only necessary for local execution on my computer

Comment: I think you should check your algorithm. It looks waaaay more complicated than necessary. Maybe trying to solve the problem again from scratch will help you find ways to simplify it.

Comment: I would check out other implementations and try to go from there, or do research then make an attempt, or check out refactoring if you dont want to scrap your current version

Comment: You don't even know what problem I'm solving with this function... how can you say that it's more complicated than necessary? i know it must be hard

Comment: I am ready to abandon the current code if there is a ready one. Does he exist?

Comment: heres an example of a [shortest path algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). It should be 'simple' to implement as the opposite

Comment: Please excuse my slow understanding, but can you please explain more on your search algorithm? Because I'm not sure what the `a` and `b` stand for

Comment: ```a``` is a row in the list, ```b``` is a column (that is, it is the upper left corner of the matrix where the search occurs). the algorithm itself is quite simple. When moving from the upper left corner to the lower right (along the main diagonal), the search is made for the first value equal to 100 in the current row and column.

Comment: The found new indexes add a recursive function for similar processing. Additionally, in addition to the row and column, it is necessary to process the indices ```a + 1```, ```b + 1```, otherwise the algorithm is incorrect. in the end, the recursive function traverses all paths and returns one path in which the number of points passed (indices of changing indices ```a```, ```b```) is maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Python shows how to do [debugging and profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/debug.html). Go around the algorithm and [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) functions to see where the bottleneck is

Comment: so I know the bottleneck is the string
```pathResult.append(find_max_path(arr[a + 1:, b + 1:], path, 1))```
. And without it, it works incorrectly, but faster

Comment: if thats the case, then you should test/profile that line to see which of those functions is the actual bottleneck: is it the `.append(...)` method or is it the `find_max_path(...)` method? Given that you have a nested while loop in `find_max_path(...)`, I'm assuming that's where the bottleneck is coming from.

Comment: I added ```break``` in two inner loops to search by row and column and the execution time was halved

Comment: UPDATE3: adding this code reduces the execution time by almost ten times!